# Как сделать resample в timeseries на основании изменении значения?

Tags: python, pandas

У меня есть timeseries
Вот пример:

```
                                    p
time    
2017-01-03 09:30:00.083000-05:00    74.6100
2017-01-03 09:30:00.505000-05:00    74.9900
2017-01-03 09:30:05.469000-05:00    74.7919
2017-01-03 09:30:08.555000-05:00    74.5000
2017-01-03 09:30:10.927000-05:00    74.9000
```

Значения в столбце 'p' иногда не меняются при изменении 'time'.
Я хочу сделать следующее: 
Алгоритм должен идти по DataFrame и:

- Если цена ('p') на следующем шаге такая же, как и на предыдущем - мы оставляем в DataFrame только первое значение.
- Если цена на следующем шаге изменилась по сравнению с предыдущим - мы записываем его в DataFrame

Получается, что мы делаем resample на основании изменения цены, но шаг изменения не имеет значения.

Помогите понять, как это сделать? 
Спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь [DataFrame.drop_duplicates()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html):

```
df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=["p"], keep="first")
```

Answer (score 0):

Исходный df:

```
                                       time      P
2017-01-03 2020-02-11 09:30:00.083000-05:00  74.61
2017-01-03 2020-02-11 09:30:00.505000-05:00  74.99
2017-01-03 2020-02-11 09:30:05.469000-05:00  74.99
2017-01-03 2020-02-11 09:30:08.555000-05:00  74.50
2017-01-03 2020-02-11 09:30:10.927000-05:00  74.50
2017-01-03 2020-02-11 09:30:11.123000-05:00  74.90
-------
time    datetime64[ns, pytz.FixedOffset(-300)]
P                                      float64
```

убираем дубликаты по столбцу P:

```
df.drop_duplicates(['P'], inplace=True)
```

Получаем:

```
                                       time      P
2017-01-03 2020-02-11 09:30:00.083000-05:00  74.61
2017-01-03 2020-02-11 09:30:00.505000-05:00  74.99
2017-01-03 2020-02-11 09:30:08.555000-05:00  74.50
2017-01-03 2020-02-11 09:30:11.123000-05:00  74.90
```